# XCode v5.1 - Choose what type when creating a new console app?

Tags: xcode

Is there possible to create a Console Application based on objective c programming language?

The current option makes it to generate an ANSI C console.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should select **Foundation** as your project type to create Foundation framework based Objective-C application.